# Unable to get entered data in a rich text editor (react-draft-wysiwyg) included to React component

Tags: reactjs, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

I am working on creating a React component with a rich text editor included. I chose react-draft-wysiwyg for editing or creating texts and then sending to the server.
I will give in the code only the functionality that causes difficulties. I use axios to send requests.
For some reason, I can’t get the correct data from the form when sending a POST request.
I checked using commands:

```
console.log(data);
console.log(this.state.editorState);
```

But there is now text typed in the form. I would like to figure it out, thanks to everyone!

Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { EditorState } from 'draft-js';
import { Editor } from 'react-draft-wysiwyg';
import '../../node_modules/react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css';
import axios from 'axios';

class AddPost extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      editorState: EditorState.createEmpty()
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
  }

  onEditorStateChange = (editorState) => {
    this.setState({
      editorState
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const data = {
      content: this.state.editorState
    };

    axios.post('http://localhost:5555/posts', {data})
      .then(res => {
        console.log(data);
      })

    this.setState({editorState: EditorState.createEmpty()})
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h5>Create document</h5>        
          <Editor
            editorState={this.state.editorState}
            wrapperClassName="demo-wrapper"
            editorClassName="demo-editor"
            onEditorStateChange={this.onEditorStateChange}
          />
          <button onClick={this.handleSubmit} className="btn-large waves-effect waves-light xbutton">Save</button>        
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AddPost;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get data from draft-js editor you need to use

```
this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent().getPlainText();
```

Comment: How to get the value in html format ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems too late but might help other using react hook form and react-draft-wysiwyg  EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(editData.description)))

```
<Controller
      control={control}
      name={"description"}
      render={({ field }) => {
      return <Editor
                   editorState={field.value}
                   toolbarClassName="toolbarClassName"
                   wrapperClassName="wrapperClassName"
                   editorClassName="editorClassName"
                   onEditorStateChange={(editorState: any) => {
                          let check = convertToRaw(editorState?.getCurrentContent())
                          setEditorDescription(JSON.stringify(check).toString())
                          field.onChange(editorState);
                        }}
                      />
        }}
/>
```